# Why in the world that I am getting these errors? SQL Server Agent job works in SQL Server 2008R2 but not in 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssis, upgrade

I am upgrading SSIS packages and SQL Server jobs and migrating them to SQL Server 2016. I have a data flow task that uses the below stored procedure as a source and loads it directly to the destination table. The package works perfectly as expected in visual studio 2016 but fails with the below error when run as a job in SQL Server 2016. However, In the same job, I've other job steps that include ssis packages that run perfectly fine, but those don't use dynamic sql.

Background information: 
Package works perfectly fine in visual studio 2008 and also as a job in SQL Server 2008R2.
Package was upgraded to Visual studio 2015 and it works perfectly fine when executed in visual studio 2015, but fails when run as a job in sql server 2016.

```
`USE [MyDb]
    GO




/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [load].[pr_Transfer_vo_DrugExposure]    Script Date: 6/27/2017 11:29:00 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [load].[pr_Transfer_vo_DrugExposure] @RegistryName VARCHAR(10), @ETLLogID Int,@debug BIT = 0
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
/**************************************************************************************************
Project:        EDW2.0
JIRA:           ?
Developer:      zbachore
Date:           2016-07-14
Description:    This stored procedure just selects rows from DrugExposure table with 
                LoadStatusID = 2. The SSIS package will use the result set. The reason we use this
                here is because the result set is dynamic - by passing RegistryName as a parameter
___________________________________________________________________________________________________
Example: EXEC load.pr_Transfer_vo_DrugExposure 'ICD', 5
___________________________________________________________________________________________________
Revision History
Date            Author          Reason for Change

-------  ------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------
***************************************************************************************************/
--Variables:
DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(2000) = ' ',
        @DrugExposure VARCHAR(100) = @RegistryName + '_vo.DrugExposure',
        @SelectSQL VARCHAR(max)

BEGIN TRY

IF 1 = 0  -- this is done only to make SSIS recognize the columns
SELECT [DrugExposureKey]
      ,[VisitOccurrenceKey]
      ,[ClientPatientID]
      ,[ClientPatientKey]
      ,[SubmissionKey]
      ,[RegistryElementID]
      ,[DrugConceptID]
      ,[DrugAdminConceptID]
      ,[EffectiveDrugDoseConceptID]
      ,[RouteConceptID]
      ,[Dosage]
      ,[DoseUnitConceptID]
      ,[NullFlavorConceptId]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[ETLLogIDInsert]
  FROM [icd_vo].[DrugExposure]



ELSE
BEGIN

SELECT @SelectSQL = '
SELECT [DrugExposureKey]
      ,[VisitOccurrenceKey]
      ,[ClientPatientID]
      ,[ClientPatientKey]
      ,[SubmissionKey]
      ,[RegistryElementID]
      ,[DrugConceptID]
      ,[DrugAdminConceptID]
      ,[EffectiveDrugDoseConceptID]
      ,[RouteConceptID]
      ,[Dosage]
      ,[DoseUnitConceptID]
      ,[NullFlavorConceptId]
      ,[Quantity]
       ,ETLLogIDInsert = ' + CAST(@ETLLogID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '
  FROM ' + @DrugExposure + ' de
  INNER JOIN etl.ETLSubmissionQueue sq ON de.SubmissionID = sq.SubmissionID
  WHERE sq.LoadStatusID = 2'

   IF @debug = 1
  PRINT @SelectSQL
  ELSE
  EXEC(@SelectSQL) 
  --PRINT @SelectSQL --for debugging only

  END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        set @ErrorMessage =  'An error occurred in stored procedure load.pr_Transfer_vo_DrugExposure ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,
               16,
               1 
               );
    END CATCH



SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

The following is the error I am getting when executing the job:

> Executed as user: MyDomain\myUser. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 13.0.1601.5 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  8:34:31 AM  Error: 2017-06-27 08:34:32.34     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: Transfer Drug Exposure vo_DrugExposure Source [55]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXEC(@SelectSQL)' in procedure 'pr_Transfer_vo_DrugExposure'  contains dynamic SQL.  Consider using the WITH RESULT SETS clause to explicitly describe the result set.".  End Error  Error: 2017-06-27 08:34:32.34     Code: 0xC020204A     Source: Transfer Drug Exposure vo_DrugExposure Source [55]     Description: Unable to retrieve column information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the database is available.  End Error  Error: 2017-06-27 08:34:32.34     Code: 0xC004706B     Source: Transfer Drug Exposure SSIS.Pipeline     Description: "vo_DrugExposure Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".  End Error  Error: 2017-06-27 08:34:32.34     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Transfer Drug Exposure SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2017-06-27 08:34:32.34     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Transfer Drug Exposure      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  8:34:31 AM  Finished: 8:34:32 AM  Elapsed:  0.5 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

I appreciate any help. Please let me know if you have any questions or need clarification.

Thank you very much!
Zed

Comment: I think your trick to use IF 1=0 is not actually working correctly due to the dynamic statement. Try using WITH RESULT SETS  (as the error states) to identify your columns for your result set.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for your suggestion! First, do you still think, that is the problem, even if it worked in SQL Server 2008R2 agent job, Visual Studio 2008, Visual Studio 2016? This is a stored procedure implemented in production for several months and it has been (and still) working fine. I have several stored procedures of this type and if that is the case, then I will have to change all of them -- see if there are other alternative ways.

Comment: I agree with Jacob's assessment.   I don't know 2016 from experience, but my first step would be to try WITH RESULT SETS and see if that fixes the problem.   In fact I would do that before I bothered researching the matter at all.

Comment: This https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1430451-3077-1.aspx implies that it could be a change as early as SQL 2012

Comment: Yes, Jacob's suggestion worked! Thanks Jacob! I was trying to avoid having to modify all the stored procedures, but looks like that is the only option right now. Thanks again all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem upgrading from SSIS 2008 to SSIS 2014. Works fine in Data Tools but fails in production. The solution is explicitly stated in the error message :)